# Embedding graphs into hyperbolic spaces

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, spectral-graph-theory, embeddings, metric-embeddings

Do we know of a characterization as to when does a graph have a "good" embedding into a hyperbolic space? (And does having such an embedding have a spectral or wavelet analysis signature?)

---

I don't know what is a good definition of a ``good" embedding is! May be my rough intuition is that there should be minimum distortion of the shortest path metric on the graph. I am open to knowing if there are other definitions which are also considered in literature.

---

Two related MO discussions (for which I don't see hyperbolic counterparts) ,

- [How hard is it to determine if a weighted graph can be isometrically embedded in R^3?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157090/how-hard-is-it-to-determine-if-a-weighted-graph-can-be-isometrically-embedded-in?rq=1)
- [Algorithm for embedding a graph with metric constraints](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33043/algorithm-for-embedding-a-graph-with-metric-constraints)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following for a start:

1. [Quantifying tree like structure in complex networks](http://web.stanford.edu/group/mmds/slides2012/s-sullivan.pdf)
2. [On the Hyperbolicity of Small-World and Tree-Like Random Graphs](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.1717)
3. [Geographic Routing Using Hyperbolic Space](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~rdk/papers/pgr.pdf)
4. [This webpage on "Embedding Networks in Hyperbolic Space"](http://bactra.org/notebooks/hyperbolic-networks.html)

Comment: Thanks! Let me see them. What would be a good reason for say complexity theorists to try embedding a graph into a hyperbolic space?

Comment: Many of these references talk of the ``$\delta$-Gromov hyperbolic" space. Can you explain why is that related to the usual $\mathbb{H}_n$?

Comment: Every CAT(k) space with $k < 0$ is $\delta$-hyperbolic...